# Function is Extremely slow with 700K Rows Data

Tags: excel, vba

Using below function which performs well on short data but whenever i move on large data set it takes long time to processing and sometime stuck.

I would appreciate if there could be another faster way to perfrom this.

```
Sub minustozeo()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 If c.Value < 0 Then
 c.Value = 0
 End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Common advice that is given: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` Saves the application a lot of processing power by not refreshing the screen during the macro. `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` Saves the application a lot of time by not requiring the sheet to be recalculated after each individual cell change. Remember to turn it back on afterwards with `= xlCalculationAutomatic`. Your data set might be too large, but its much faster to work in an array rather than as sheet ranges. You can take ranges into arrays very easily like `myArr = myRange.Value` and vice versa.

Comment: Roughly what % of the 700k rows are being updated?

Comment: Sure i will keep this thing in practice while using macrso @Toddleson

Comment: Almost 70% data is being updated through code. @Tim Williams

Comment: What is wrong with modifying the [SuperUser solution](https://superuser.com/a/1702759) you got from JohnSUN? Maybe there are just some minor details that need to get fixed.

Comment: I agree with your opinion but i am not an expert i can create short code according to requirments but that tricky functions are hard to modify. @VBasic2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a faster method using the array approach:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, t, rngVis As Range, rngVals As Range
    Dim arr, r As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngVals = ws.Range("A2:A500000") 'range to operate on
    
    'create some dummy data with about 70% < 0
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    With rngVals
        .Formula = "=RAND()-0.7"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    rngVals.Copy rngVals.Offset(, 2) 'for verification only...
    
    'autofilter
    rngVals.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<0", Operator:=xlAnd
        
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngVis = rngVals.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngVis Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no cells found
    
    Debug.Print rngVis.Cells.Count 'approx 350k
    
    t = Timer
    arr = rngVals.Value 'read the data
    For Each c In rngVis.Cells
        If c.Value < 0 Then arr(c.Row - 1, 1) = 0 ' -1 because first array value is from row #2
    Next c
    rngVals.Value = arr     'write the altered data back
    Debug.Print Timer - t   ' ~1 sec
    
    ws.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Comment: I thought that it would be too large for an array. What is the limit for arrays? Excel numbers are `Variant/Double`, how many of them can be put into an array before the computer explodes?

Comment: A Double is 8 bytes, so a million of those (plus some overhead for the array I guess) shouldn't make too much of a dent on a modern PC?   Around 7.8MB